# Center command bar buttons in windows uwp

Tags: c#, windows, mobile, win-universal-app

is there a way to move a command bar button to 50% bar width? New buttons are always stuck to the right and I want them to be centered:

[App bar button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLWrv.png)

But changing the HorizontalAlignment property to center won't move it. The only thing that seems to work is to work with margins - but I can't use them since the position will differ for different resolutions.

XAML Code looks like this:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar Background="#FFFF8B00" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="360" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="True" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Padding="0">
        <AppBarButton x:Name="button" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Icon="Account" Label="button" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="Height"/>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get the real-time view of the `CommandBar` with [Live Visual Tree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270227.aspx), you can see that the `AppBarButton`s are all in the `PrimaryItemsControl`:

[image]

As you can see in the picture, there is a `ContentControl` in the `CommandBar`, which has the same level with `PrimaryItemsControl`.

So you can check the [CommandBar styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299118.aspx), please copy the Default style of `CommandBar` to your page resource, and find the `PrimaryItemsControl` in this style, by default it's like this:

```
<ItemsControl
    x:Name="PrimaryItemsControl"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
    MinHeight="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeMinHeight}"
    IsTabStop="False"
    Grid.Column="1">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

It will stay in the Column 1 of a `Grid` which is named "ContentRoot", and share space with `ContentControl`, now you can edit this `PrimaryItemsControl` like this:

```
<ItemsControl
    x:Name="PrimaryItemsControl"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    MinHeight="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeMinHeight}"
    IsTabStop="False"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

It is quite simple, but you need to consider that if you want to add some content in your `CommandBar.Content`, your `AppBarButton`s may overlay on your content. But if you won't use `CommandBar.Content`, then it's OK to do this work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this xaml code

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar IsOpen="False" IsSticky="True" Background="#FFFF8B00" UseLayoutRounding="True">
        <AppBarButton Name="button" Icon="Account" Label="button" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </AppBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Comment: Thanks but is this also possible with the command bar? The app bar doesnt seem to support primary / secondary controls.

Comment: Try this solution, add your own grid to <Page.BottomAppBar> http://stackoverflow.com/a/32210614/4727426